# Verify table items - best way

Tags: selenium, verify

I have a table and need to verify items(text) within every single cell
Now, the question is not about fetching rows,columns, etc but the best logic way to do that?

I'm using selenium and I'm not sure if the best way is to verify every single cell by passing row,column (verify(row1,col1.... or maybe fetching through the table and check( but I don't know  how to pass my parameters) 
Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: write what you have done and then help may come.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the row and column numbers to your function. In the function to can get the text -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='tableId']/tbody/tr[rownum]/td[colnum]")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not a efficient html parser. I assume you are using java,since you haven't mentioned, You can get page source and assign it to String like;

```
String web_page = driver.getPageSource();
```

and then using Jsoup;

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(web_page);
```

after that point you can select any element of the page like;

```
String first_link_on_the_page = doc.getElementById("a").first();
   //first_link_on_the_page will be the href="" value of <a>
```

If you are using any language other than Java, I'm not able to help but hope it may give you an idea.